# Is there a way to only show certain percentages in a piechart using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

outer_sizes = [5, 17, 20, 25, 33]
inner_sizes = [1, 4, 5, 12, 6, 14, 4, 21, 9, 24]
outer_colors = ['#499894', '#B07AA1', '#59A14F', '#F28E2B', '#4E79A7']
inner_colors = ['white', '#86BCB6', 'white', '#D4A6C8', 'white', '#8CD17D', 'white', '#FFBE7D',
                'white', '#A0CBE8']

plt.pie(outer_sizes,colors=outer_colors, startangle=90,frame=True, radius=4)
plt.pie(inner_sizes,colors=inner_colors,radius=3,startangle=90,autopct='%1.0f%%',
       pctdistance=0.8, textprops={'size':22})
center_circle = plt.Circle((0,0), 2, color='black', fc='white', linewidth=0)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(center_circle)
fig.set_size_inches(12,12)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This code produces the following chart:
[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to only show the percent labels on the inner donut for just the colored segments. In other words, I do not want the white slices to have any labels.

Comment: You could create an array of strings for labels with "white" segments set to "" and colored segments set to the formatted percentage. `labels= [] for i in range(0,len(inner_sizes), 2)]: labels.append(format(inner_sizes[i])) labels.append("")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be just to explicitly put in the labels. Swap this line in in your code:

```
labels = []
for i, e in enumerate(inner_sizes):
    if i%2 != 0:
        labels.append('{}%'.format(e))
    else:
        labels.append('')

plt.pie(inner_sizes,colors=inner_colors,radius=3,startangle=90,labeldistance=.8,
       pctdistance=0.8, textprops={'size':22}, labels=labels)
```

Comment: In a more general fashion, you could generate the labels from the values: `inner_labels = [("%1.0f%%"%(value) if color != "white" else "") for value, color in zip(inner_sizes, inner_colors)]` - Also note that you need to replace the `pctdistance` argument with the `labeldistance` argument of the same value to have the same placement.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the auto percentage texts and set those invisible where the background is white. The benefit compared to the other answer is that you don't need to fake the labels (and it would still work if there were actual labels present).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

outer_sizes = [5, 17, 20, 25, 33]
inner_sizes = [1, 4, 5, 12, 6, 14, 4, 21, 9, 24]
outer_colors = ['#499894', '#B07AA1', '#59A14F', '#F28E2B', '#4E79A7']
inner_colors = ['white', '#86BCB6', 'white', '#D4A6C8', 'white', '#8CD17D', 'white', '#FFBE7D',
                'white', '#A0CBE8']

plt.pie(outer_sizes,colors=outer_colors, startangle=90,frame=True, radius=4)
_, _, autopct = plt.pie(inner_sizes,colors=inner_colors,radius=3,startangle=90,autopct='%1.0f%%',
                        pctdistance=0.8, textprops={'size':22})
for txt, c in zip(autopct, inner_colors):
    if c == "white":
        txt.set_visible(False)

center_circle = plt.Circle((0,0), 2, color='black', fc='white', linewidth=0)
plt.gca().add_artist(center_circle)

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12,12)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]